# Why do I get an error that I'm referring to a non-existent object in my Class circle?

Tags: python, class, oop, compiler-errors, geometry

I'm trying to write a class circle and this is my first experience with OOP, to do so I wrote a Point class also, but when I run the contains and intersect function I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'center'
```

This is the code:

```
import math


class Point():
    """ Holds data on a point (x,y) in the plane """

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        assert isinstance(x,(int, float)) and isinstance(y,(int, float)) 
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ")"


    #getters
    def x_val(self):
        return self.x

    def y_val(self):
        return self.y

#end of class Point 




class Circle():
    """ Holds data on a circle in the plane """

    def __init__(self,*args):
        if len(args)==2:
            if isinstance(args[0],Point) and isinstance(args[1],(float,int)):
                assert args[1]>0
                self.center= args[0]
                self.radius= args[1]

        if len(args)==3:
            assert args[2]>0
            self.a=args[0]
            self.b=args[1]
            self.center= Point(self.a,self.b)
            self.radius= args[2]


    def __repr__(self):
        return "Circle centered at " + str(self.center) + " with radius " + str(self.radius)



    def contains(self,check): #ERROR!!!

        if isinstance(check,(Point)):
           if math.sqrt(((Point.x_val(self.center))-(Point.x_val(check.center)))**2 + ((Point.y_val(check.center))-(Point.y_val(check.center)))**2) <= self.radius:
               return True
        if isinstance(check,Circle): 
            test= math.sqrt(((Point.x_val(self.center))-(Point.x_val(check.center)))**2 + ((Point.y_val(self.center))-(Point.y_val(check.center))**2))
            if test < (abs((self.radius)-(check.radius))):
                return True

        else:
            return False

    def intersect(self,other):  #ERROR!!!
        check= math.sqrt(((Point.x_val(self))-(Point.x_val(other)))**2 + ((Point.y_val(self))-(Point.y_val(other)))**2)
        if check >(self.radius+other.radius):
            return False
        if check < (self.radius+other.radius):
            return True


    def draw(self,mat):
        for i in mat:
            for j in i:
                if Circle.contains(i,j):
                    mat[i[j]]==1
```

Comment: 168 lines of code? At the very least, give a complete traceback and the code that reproduces it (i.e. not just your classes but also how you use them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instances of the class `Point` do not have an attribute `center`, in these three lines of code you assume they do:

```
if isinstance(check,(Point)):
           if math.sqrt(((Point.x_val(self.center))-(Point.x_val(check.center)))**2 + ((Point.y_val(check.center))-(Point.y_val(check.center)))**2) <= self.radius:
               return True
```

If `check` is an instance of `Point` don't refer to `check.center`.

BTW, please give the full stack trace when asking questions like these, not just the last line. With the full trace I could have just looked at the line with the error instead of having to look through the rest of the code.

What you probably wanted was just to access the x value of the Circle's center and the x of the check Point.

```
if isinstance(check,(Point)):
    if math.sqrt((self.center.x-check.x)**2 + (self.center.y-check.y)**2) <= self.radius:
           return True
```

Note that using a method to access an attribute is considered not to be good style in Python. If you want to access the value of an attribute just access the attribute directly. In some languages this can problems if later you need to change how an object is implemented but in Python you can change an attribute into a property at any time without breaking code.

Comment: I understood my mistake, but how am I supposed to rephrase it? i.e how can I refer to the x value in the Circle class?

Comment: You refer to the `x` attribute the same way you refer to any attribute: `self.center.x` and `check.x` will give you the attributes you wanted. I've updated my answer to explain further.